# JsonIgnoreProperties not working , Infinite recursion - Kotlin/Spring/

Tags: json, spring, kotlin

Hello i have 2 tables with relation ManyToMany but i am getting this error after if fetch from the api:

```
 Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
```

My Classes are ManyToMany as example:

Class A:

```
  @ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY , cascade = [
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    ])
    @JoinTable(name = "material_formula_material_set",
            joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "material_formula_id", referencedColumnName = "id")],
            inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "material_set_id", referencedColumnName = "id")]
    )
    val materialSet: Set<MaterialSet>?,
```

And Class B:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "materialSet")
val materialFormulas: Set<MaterialFormula>?,
```

I also tried to use  `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` and `JsonIgnore` to one of them but still not working :\

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate a reference to your parent class in your child class with `@JsonIgnore` annotation. Since it is many to many relationship it might be  not that obvious to see who is parent and who is the child. But in any case the infinite recursion occurs because class A references B and B in turn references A. So, lets say in B you will need to annotate reference to A with `@JsonIgnore` and it will solve the problem

Comment: I added ```@JsonIgnore``` to class B but the issue still happens :<

Comment: Look carefully at the stacktrace you might see the chain of looping.